# How to stub new KafkaSink on integration test

Tags: java, apache-flink

Flink 1.14 marks `FlinkKafkaProducer` deprecated and replaces it with the new `KafkaSink` class.
I'm trying to put a new approach into `MiniClusterWithClientResource` integration tests similar as described here: [Testing Flink jobs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#testing-flink-jobs).

Unfortunately, I'm having issues stubbing the new `KafkaSink` class as it inherits from an awkward `Sink` interface with Flink internal generic types. Also `KafkaSink` class itself exposes only a package-private constructor - therefore it's impossible to inherit from it from the arbitrary java package and overload its behavior.

I managed to overcome the issue by inheriting from `KafkaSink` class in my own `apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink` package, however, there must be a better way of handling the testing or the new API is not really test friendly.

```
package org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink;

import org.apache.flink.api.connector.sink.Committer;
import org.apache.flink.api.connector.sink.GlobalCommitter;
import org.apache.flink.api.connector.sink.SinkWriter;
import org.apache.flink.core.io.SimpleVersionedSerializer;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public abstract class TestKafkaSink<T> extends KafkaSink<T> {
    public abstract void writeValue(T value);
    public abstract void clear();

    public TestKafkaSink() {
        super(null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public SinkWriter<T, KafkaCommittable, KafkaWriterState> createWriter(InitContext context, List<KafkaWriterState> states) {
        return new SinkWriter<>() {
            @Override
            public void write(T t, Context context) {
                writeValue(t);
            }

            @Override
            public List<KafkaCommittable> prepareCommit(boolean b) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void close() {

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Committer<KafkaCommittable>> createCommitter() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<GlobalCommitter<KafkaCommittable, Void>> createGlobalCommitter() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<SimpleVersionedSerializer<KafkaCommittable>> getCommittableSerializer() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<SimpleVersionedSerializer<Void>> getGlobalCommittableSerializer() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<SimpleVersionedSerializer<KafkaWriterState>> getWriterStateSerializer() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach taken in Flink's integration tests for the KafkaSink is to bring up a containerized instance of Kafka, rather than mocking it. For example, you could look at https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.14/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/sink/KafkaSinkITCase.java.

Not sure how helpful this will prove to be in this case, but in general I find looking at Flink's own tests is a good strategy for figuring out how the developers intended the interfaces to be used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree, using Testconainers would be one approach, however, it's quite heavy and would require us to rewrite existing tests into more integration-like abstraction layer. I hoped that new API would provide something lighter to stub and not to rely on specific (KafkaSink) implementation.